# SignalR ClaimsIdentity Null Bearer token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, claims-based-identity, signalr-hub, bearer-token

I am having some trouble accessing my userId after and creating my dictionary with connectionIds. I currently and using OAuthBearer for authentication of my users and saving information into ClaimsIdentity, something like below:

```
            public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {

            IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id));


            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { 
                    "as:client_id", (context.ClientId == null) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId
                },
                { 
                    "userName", context.UserName
                },
                { 
                    "userId", user.Id
                }
            });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
            context.Validated(ticket);
        }

    }
```

When I am in my startup/my signalR hub, when I try using the IRequest.user.identity.name or `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();`, I get an empty value.

```
public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
        {
            var userId = request.User.Identity.Name;
            return userId.ToString();
        }
```

I'm thinking that something is wrong with my claims because I can't access the values of UserId and userName. If I run `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();` anywhere else, I can get the userId.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try replacing `HttpContext.Current` with
`Context.Request.GetHttpContext()` inside your signalR hub methods.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubcallercontext(v=vs.118).aspx) the HubCallerContext returns the context of the client.